# AS3: getCharBoundaries() returns null

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been seeing this issue on and off when I use `getCharBoundaries()` and I'm not quite sure what's causing it. Some text I have is completely okay with it, other times it throws a fit.

Here's my code

```
while (copy.text.indexOf("{") != -1) //copy is a proprietary textnode type object
{
    var char:String = "tf"

    var searchString:String = "{" + char + "}";
    var index:int = copy.text.indexOf(searchString);

    var bounds:Object = copy.content.getCharBoundaries(index); //content is a flash textField
    //sprite is created elsewhere, it is not the issue
    sprite.x = copy.x + bounds.x + 4; //here we sometimes get the error that bounds is null
    sprite.y = copy.y + bounds.y - 2;


    //replace the string we used with characters that are easy to hide with the sprite and take up a decent width
    copy.text = copy.text.replace(searchString, "---" ); 
}
```

The one that breaks has 2 of the sub-strings we want to remove (called "{tf}". The 2nd one always breaks, even if I remove the first one from the string entirely. The string is not something I can post publicly as it is part of work, but suffice it to say that there are two paragraphs separated by 1 line (that is, two "returns" were typed into it). However, if I remove all of the returns, the 2nd one STILL breaks.

As much as my research has told me, it's just that `getCharBoundaries()` doesn't like certain characters -- punctuation most of the time -- but 99% of the time when I pass in a string, it works fine. I was hoping someone could possibly explain why `getCharBoundaries()` returns null (the documentation does not explain this) and what I can do to fix it.

I've tried to get all the indexes BEFORE replacing the string, but i ran into the same issues

Comment: if copy is a TextField object as you claim where is the content property coming from? Also getCharBounds() does not seem to exist anywhere, where is that method coming from? You actually never use that method in your code either.

Comment: sorry, copy is our proprietary text node object, it has a text, which is a string, and it's content is a "textField". textFields have a getCharBounds function that returns an object containing the relative position and size of a char at a given index

Comment: can't see a getCharBounds() method in TextField docs.Your own code is not using that but using getCharBoundaries(). Are you purposely calling that method by a different name?

Comment: not on purpose, no. My bad, getCharBoundaries is what I mean

Comment: `getCharBoundaries()` will return null if there is line break for example. But you passing "{tf}" index so it's not line brake, right? Maybe make sure your index is valid - if you search for "{tf}" and there is no such substring `indexOf()` will return -1 and when you pass -1 to `getCharBoundries()` you will get null. Note that if you string is "{ tf}"(cantain space) for example your index is -1 because there is no "{tf}" inside it.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos there are line breaks, but even if I remove all of them I get null. The index used is never -1, according to my debugging. it's all perfectly valid indexes returning null.

Comment: are you saying that index allways points to "{" character and one time method return null and the other valid rectangle?

Comment: i just fired it 10M times and got 0 nulls.

Comment: yup! that's what I'm saying, certain strings it doesnt like, some it does. The index points to the "{", and then AT THAT INDEX, we get the x and y location from getCharBoundaries. Then, we use 'replace()' to replace all 4 characters with 3 dashes, which the sprite sits over top of.

Comment: If it's true then you should report a bug to adobe. I'm not able to reproduce your problem on my machine. Can you provide fragment of string where you get this error? Do you use any special font? What are settings of your TextField? Also, you search for string in copy.text and try to get boundaries from copy.content - are you sure those allways contain the same string?

Comment: i am reasonably sure that they are the same, but it's worth looking into. As far as the string goes, probably not. Confidential and all that. I realize it's extremely helpful to have that, but it's out of my hands. I've looked the string over, and nothing I do really seems to change it. I removed the returns so that it was one paragraph, still hated it, removed punctuation (like colons) still nothing. the only thing that mattered was removing the 2nd {tf}, and only the 2nd one. Removing the first didn't help. But I have other strings that have 2 {tf}s that work just fine

Comment: @PawełAudionysos if you're interested, I managed to solve it. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the issue we managed to solve. After trying to get a symbol on every line, we found it breaking after the 3rd line every time.

This helped us figure out that *our textfield was too small*. `getCharBoundaries()` is trying to find a relative point in space beyond it's width and height, and it doesn't like that. The text was spilling out of the textfield, as it is made to do, so the height of the textfield is never an issue for us until now. For all we knew, the textfield's boundaries were as large as the text appeared, but this was not the case.

Comment: I didn't even thought about it. This method worked even if TF was not on the scene so who could think of that it will fail if character is outside TF bounds... :) You would avoid this problem if there was no lack of documentation but adobe is still relatively good at this, I think.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos Yeah for real.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do if creating a textfield dynamically, is add an enterframe listener, to essentially skip to the next frame, where the textfield will be updated with the new height and width parameter.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, validate);

private function validate(e:Event):void
{
   removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, validate);
   txt.getCharBounds(yourIndexHere);

}
```